# How can I backup my SMS

Tags: backup, sms

I need to restore my phone.

How can I make a backup of my text messages on my computer?
Is it possible to restore text messages on the new phone?

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible with Windows Phone.

It is a often requested feature and microsoft is reviewing it now. you can vote for this feature on Windows Phone user voice [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-backup?ref=title)

Answer (score 6):

This is not yet possible with the windows phone OS. For certain unlocked devices there is a utility called [SMS backup](http://wmpoweruser.com/sms-backup-and-restore-for-unlocked-windows-phones-demoed/) which will allow you to do this.

Comment: this utility only works on first generation Samsung WP7 devices. Devices from other brands and later Samsung devices have an interop lock and therefore this app doesn't work on those devices.

Comment: Bump! The utility got updated. Now it works under the WP Root Tools, which has exploits for these: Samsung first and second generation devices; LG devices; HTC first generation devices with Mango v1 drivers (SPL 4.x or lower); Samsung first generation devices with custom ROM and Full Unlock; HTC first generation devices with custom ROM and Full Unlock.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to backup you SMS on Windows Phone. Here are the steps (Windows Phone 8.1). However, you need a microSD card for this.

1. Insert microSD card if not already available.
2. Open the [Transfer my Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr?rtc=1) app (download and install if you don't have it already).
3. Once the app opens up, expand the app bar by tapping on the small 3 dots [...] at the bottom right corner of the app.
4. Tap on "export to SD card".
5. Once the app finishes searching the phone, select the checkbox for "Text Messages". You may also check "MMS" if needed.
6. Click on the "Start" button to start the backup process.
7. The app will display the progress of the backup process. While the backup is going on, do NOT switch to the start screen or to another app since this will stop the backup process.
8. Once the backup is complete, your backup will be available in the following location of your phone: D:\backup\Data\<date and time stamp>\Sms (where D = your microSD card)

You may access this on the phone using [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/files/9wzdncrfj3pl?rtc=1) or any other file management app.

Comment: Can this app keep the backup messages received through Whatspp for a selected contack or whole?

Comment: @djgharphalia07 This app will backup SMS messages only. Whatsapp has an inbuilt backup feature. For more details refer [Whatsapp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/22548236) and [this answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12743/18061).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this well-hidden feature that actually allows to backup contacts without having to upload them to a cloud!

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Windows Phone 8, you can backup text messages to the cloud and restore them on a new phone. You can activate this in Settings > Backup. To learn more about this feature you can visit the help page:

[Backup my stuff](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff)

Comment: Is there any way to view all smsm online ? On outlook.com, I can received sms but not sms that I've sent

Comment: There is currently no way to view these online

Answer (score 0):

You can't backup your sms on computer. But you can backup it on cloud go to Settings ->backup. Once you backup on cloud you can restore it in new phone.

Answer (score 0):

[contacts+messages backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm) app can be used to take a backup of your SMS and contacts.

1. This app will be located in Settings. Hence go to
   *Settings -> Contacts + messages backup*.
2. Now select backup option.
3. Select SMS, MMS or Contacts and click backup.
4. You can restore the backup from an another phone.

**Notes** :

- To use this app, please go to Settings on your Windows Phone. This app will NOT appear in your list of installed apps.
- The app will recover backups only if it is present in the folder
  named 'backup+restore' on the SD card.
- Restoring a backup of messages from a dual SIM Windows Phone restores
  all messages to message store for the first SIM/slot.