# What can be backed up?

Tags: apps, backup, sms, games, history

I just read this Q: [How can I backup my SMS](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms)

I am curious about what any other thing IS or IS NOT possible to back up in my phone?

I expect a list of things that CAN be backed up a list of those that CAN'T be.

I can think of these data:

- SMS
- phone calls history
- people / contact list
- connections in contact list (more accounts associated with one person)
- music
- pictures
- general settings
- home screen tiles
- installed apps/games info
- apps/games data

If you can think of anything else, feel free to add it.

Comment: SMS - possible. See here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms/9208#9208

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Music & Pictures**
Your music and pictures can be synced through zune so you have a backup there.

**Contacts**
You can store your contacts in your live account or exchange account. This way your contacts will always be synced through all your devices / computers

Connected contacts won't be stored anywhere

**Apps**
All the apps you bought/downloaded are stored by microsoft. On the windowsphone.com website you can see a [list](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/account) of all the apps you've installed before. There is an app called reinstaller that can help you reinstall all the apps in a quicker way than just browsing the marketplace searching for your app: [Reinstaller](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-US/apps/b9d1115b-2c0d-4e5d-afc6-fa6dcd84dda4)

You can view a list of bought/downloaded apps on the WindowsPhone.com website here:
https://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/account

Your home screen tiles won't be backupped anywhere since this connected to your installed apps which aren't backupped aswell (only complete list of downloaded/bought apps available)

App data will also not be backupped.

**SMS & Call History**
Not possible at this moment

**Settings**
Not possible at this moment

Comment: Where exactly can I found list of apps I installed before? I just got updated Zune (which removed WP7 marketplace). Can it be viewed on the web marketplace?

Comment: @jumbo added the url to the web marketplace where you can find the list

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Comment: At least with Windows 10 Mobile it is now possible to backup contacts, SMS and MMS locally to the SD-card (no need to upload it to any cloud!) using the *Transfer my Data*-app (see [here](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms/9208#9208)). If you update your answer accordingly, you have my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an update in case anyone comes across this question: as many likely know now, WP8 has since updated the ability to backup sms/calls/settings by default - you simply need to turn on the feature in the backup menu within the settings hub; backups will be stored with the associated M$ account, and can be restored by linking up the account with your new/restored phone.