# Is there any way to backup my entire phone?

Tags: backup, homebrew

From [this question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-can-be-backed-up) we know what can and can't currently be backed up. Are there any 3rd party tools or homebrew apps that will let me back up **everything** and restore it to a different device?  I recently upgraded to a Lumia 900, and having such tool would have saved me a few hours.

It is OK if the device has to be developer-unlocked or rooted.

I did look at [How can I backup my SMS](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms), but that only covers SMS, and appears to be looking for any official way. I'm looking for possible 3rd part alternatives.

Comment: You can also look here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-can-be-backed-up

Comment: @jumbo I *linked* to that question in mine, and am specifically looking for something that CAN back them up. That question/answer is a great reference for what can be done officially, but as I stated several time, I'm looking for something non-official.

Comment: I read this question on mobile and I overlooked several things in your post. I am sorry for that. Answer you got from Thomas is great, so thank you for your question! Vote up!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the OS has no built in feature that will allow you to backup everything and restore. Looks like its [coming though](http://www.wpcentral.com/phone-backups-coming-next-version-windows-phone). Excerpt:

> A recent posting on Microsoft's jobs site reveals that phone backup and easy restore will be available in the next version of Windows Phone.

Yes, there is a homebrew app called [WP7 Backup](http://master.wpcentral.com/wp7-backup-tool-homebrew). Excerpt:

> A member over at the XDA Developer forum, by the username hx4700Killer, has come up with a backup tool for your Windows Phone 7 device. It's a simple .Net program that allows users to backup their device via Zune and can be used for restoration when you use the "update" option.

Comment: Sweet, I never knew that tool existed. Thanks Thomas!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Mac then you can backup via Windows Phone Connector for Mac. Not sure why Microsoft gave Mac users a manual backup option but not Zune users.
[image]

Source: http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/windows-phone-7-connector-browse-and-backup-files-sync-itunes-mac/