# How Can I Change My Microsoft Account?

Tags: settings, microsoft-account

When I initially setup my Windows Phone 7, I used my work Microsoft Account. Now I want to change it to my personal one. How can I change the Microsoft Account I initially used to set up the phone?

When I tap and hold on the Microsoft Account account I can't delete it, and it won't let me edit the email address, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At this time you can't change your Live ID. The only way would be to reset your phone, and run the setup again.

```
Setting -> about -> reset your phone
```

Pair this with the backup ideas mentioned at [What can I Backup](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-can-be-backed-up) and [How can I backup my entire phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/151/is-there-any-way-to-backup-my-entire-phone), and it shouldn't be too painful. Perhaps we will get the official feature soon.

Comment: Do you know if this applies to Windows Phone 8 as well?

Comment: @walter, yes it does