# Computer Initial set-up

Tags: microsoft-account

How can I change the E-mail address I initially set-up when setting up this computer? When I First initially set-up my e-mail address it was type in incorrectly can you help me correct this error?

Comment: Can you log in into your computer

Comment: Computer? This site is for questions about Windows Phone and Windows 10 on smartphones. If your question is about using Windows on a PC, try http://superuser.com

Comment: And if you asking about your phone, see also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/205/106