# Where does WhatsApp store backups in windows phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, apps, whatsapp

In the WhatsApp settings menu there is a "backup" option. I would like to know where this backup will be stored in the phone. Is it possible to restore this backup?

Answer (score 3):

This backup is stored somewhere in the phone's [internal memory](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/23607796). You can restore a backup through the WhatsApp application if your phone isn't damaged. Additionally, you can [email](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/22548236) chats to create a safe backup, but you cannot use it to restore your chats on your phone.

Comment: Yeah i understood Backup will be saved in phone's internal memory. Can you please explain briefly how to restore backup using whatsApp App?

Comment: According to the help page I linked, all you have to do is [uninstall and reinstall](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/21478066) WhatsApp.

Answer (score 2):

The backup from Whatsapp will be located on

*SDCard->Whatsapp->WinPhoneBackup*

[image: Whatsapp backup folder]

> Is it possible to restore this backup?

Yes it is possible to restore from Backup. But restoration is only possible when installing Whatsapp as [@akid](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/1788/akid) said in [his answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/2326/18061). If you want to restore a backup you will have to reinstall the app.

Upon reinstall you will get a prompt to restore message from backup. Follow the on-screen instructions.

[image: Whatsapp Message restore]

**References** :

1. [How do I save my chat history? - Whatsapp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/22548236)
2. [How do I restore my messages? - Whatsapp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/23607796)