# Is there anyway to find Whatsapp backup in a Windows Phone with no SD Card?

Tags: lumia, whatsapp, backup

I don't know where my backup is stored in my Lumia 930. It doesn't have SD Card but the app is still able to make backups.

I'm pretty sure the back ups can't go anywhere else but my phone, still I can't find them anywhere.

Any ideas on how can I see the backup files?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like question is already answered on SO Please check this link http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/where-does-whatsapp-store-backups-in-windows-phone-8 As well as check this other link http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/295308-restore-whatsapp-backup-new-phone.html I hope this help you somewhat.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/where-does-whatsapp-store-backups-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: It will be there somewhere in internal memory for sure but viewing that backup file may be i am not sure whether can view but can restore that without any trouble also can save the chats in email it's like backup chats to emails that option also available.

Comment: Is not the same question. The other question is general, about where is it stored. This question is specific about phones without SD Cards and how to retrieve the files, not how to restore the backup already saved in the same phone. That's why I thought it was good to open a separate question. I read that question before creating mine btw.