# SMS Backup : where are sms that I've sent?

Tags: sms, backup, outlook

I've got a WP8.1 phone and I activated SMS backup a few days ago.
After several tests, I can finally view my sms message on outlook.com via Category Filters.

However, I can only see my received sms, not messages that I've sent. Is it possible to view them ? Are they included in the backup ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I backup my SMS](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to view these online. For some users, it is not possible to even view the received messages on outlook.com.

If you want to view your backed up messages, currently the only way to do so is by following the steps in my answer to this question:
[How can I backup my SMS](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/102/how-can-i-backup-my-sms)