# How to recover text messages?

Tags: lumia, sms, messaging, nokia-lumia-1520

I had my back-up on, but I mistakenly deleted my few text messages. I was wondering if there is any way that I can recover them back. It is very important, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry you cannot, Cause you had back-up on. It will also delete from cloud. There's no way to recover them back.

Suggestion: Go to back-up and check your last back-up. If your last Back-up time  Was showing before deleting text time, then you can. and also check text back-up too.

Source: [Windows phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff)

Comment: how can I restore back-up thou?? I cannot see any option to check or restore back-up in Lumia 1520.

Comment: Reset phone. Then it will ask you, to restore back up. then you have to click 'yes' and sign in. That's the only way. you cant check sms' in outlook or onedrive.

Comment: what if it didn't backup anything at all. In that case I will lose all of my data?? Is there anyway that I can make sure that back-up is saved somewhere??

Comment: In settings > bacup, tap on apps+settings and it will say something like "Last backed up about 2 weeks ago" above the [ back up now ] button

Comment: Or you can backup text messages manually to your SD card as shown in the link below. This way you can restore at any point WITHOUT resetting your phone.  http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9208/11777

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you back up your text messages before resetting. After setting up your phone, go to settings--back up--switch on text message back up,--it will ask you (DOWNLOAD MESSAGES FROM THE PAST ONE MONTH, THE PAST YEAR OR ANYTIME {In my own case, i selected anytime}) from the drop-down options. And i got ALL my past text messages of more than a year back. 
My phone: LUMIA 535.